# Transform � to its correspondant char

Tags: javascript, formatting

I read data from a CSV (Comma separated) exported from Excel.
Getting the content with the angular directive $http.
Parsing it with a function that I found on the interweb

But, the document is encoded in 'ANSI' and so when i'm displaying the text I've got several "?" like this : "le scan g�n�r� par le serveur"

Possible value could be accents "é", quote '"', '...'...

I've tried to :

- -Export from Excel with UTF-8 encoding : didn't work, encoding seem's not change
- -Iterate on each char of the data, and replace the value based on the hex value : didn't work, their all coded with the value 'fffd' even
  if, on notepadd++ they appears with different value (like X93, X94,
  X92...)
- -Import, read and display it ANSI encoded, didn't work, maybe i've didn't do it correctly
- -Use a script found to translate it to UTF-8 : didn't work, the ? were replaced by two "special charactere" (all the same)

More over, the solution i need should be "very" user friendly, as people juse have to modify the inital Excel and save it as csv.

**So my problem is : how can I display the original sentence ?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` of the http call to the correct format? `Content-Type: text/csv; charset= ???` I'm hoping`Content-Type: text/csv; charset=windows-1252` works, maybe one of the other 2 ANSI sets.

Comment: Yes, within the point 3 i tried, charset UTF-8, ansi or windows 1252, nothing works...